# Want code for a modular operation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given numbers `a1` and `a2` and a positive integer `k`, such that `a3 = Mod[a1 a2, k]`, `a4 = Mod[a1 a3, k]` and so on, I want the Mathematica code that can compute the value of `{a1, a2, a3, a4, ..., an}` stopping at a point where a particular condition is met.

Comment: Look up `NestList[]`. If your actual problem is the implementation of an MLCG, look up the docs for `SeedRandom[]`.

Answer (score 1):

In Mathematica this sort of computation is usually done with [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html). Here is an example.

```
With[{k = 7, a = 3, b = 5, n = 11}, Prepend[NestList[Mod[a #, k] &, b, n], a]]
```

> `{3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4}`

Note this shows a cycle length of 7, the maximum length possible with `k = 7`.

#### Update

I add this to meet the additional requirements stated by the OP in a comment below.

```
generator[a1_, a2_, k_, test_] := 
  Rest @ NestWhileList[Mod[a1 #, k] &, a2, test, 1, 2 k]
generator[3, 5, 7, # != 2 &]
```

> `{1, 3, 2}`

Comment: thanks for that prompt reply but first, I do not want a1 and a2 included in the output. Secondly, I would like the computation to stop at a point say where an is 2 first which in your example above is at n=3 excluding a1 and a2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @myg, "I do not want a1 and a2 included in the output" - then use `Drop[]`. For your other concern, look up `NestWhileList[]`.